# GNUPLOT generated curves to view in single frame one by one back and forth

Tags: latex, gnuplot, pdflatex

I have a lot of data to plot in a single plot window and it looks really ugly and not understandable. Moreover  legends are coming on to the curves which make curves unreadable. I cannot put curve alone  one by one into my latex report which makes it again difficult to maneuver between the plots.

My question is- can't it be possible to put all the curves in single plot generated from gnu plot which can be easily maneuver back and forth in a single plot window the latex report?

I know a bit about tikz pictures where no of frameworks can be easily accessible in single plot.

can't it be used for a whole curves one by one assuming as different frame work. and at last all the plots in the the plot window.

It would be very helpful if is possible so.

I have data with N rows and M columns in it. I need plots of N rows vs. each column separately to be shown in each frame in *Latex* generated report and in the last frame all the curves should be present. I need a proper procedure to follow to animate the curves.

Comment: Just to make it clear: Do you mean something like here, where you can toggle the data by clicking (1) ? http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo_canvas/ However, I don't think it's possible in gnuplot alone. Also, such thinks are no good idea when it comes to printing on paper. It may be better to sort the curves and put them on a few plots. Or choose a completely different way to visualize it.

Comment: I know it would not be done standalone in GUNUPLOT. Latex is also required to post process the graphs. but how to include in latex in better way that's what I wanted to know?? for that what format of graphs can be generated from the GNUPLOT?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this kind of thing can be done with the `animate` package in latex. I have successfully used it in the past for presentations that I put together with `beamer`. You could switch between different gnuplot graphs that are loaded into the `animateinline` environment, but you can also use `pgfplots` within `tikz` to modify the plot directly on your latex document without need for an external plot.

Using `animate` requires investing a bit of time at the beginning but the results can be very nice. Also, Okular (and I'm guessing other PDF viewers as well) seem to have trouble visualizing the animations but Adobe reader (`acroread` on linux) loads them without problems.

As an example, you can check a 5-minute [presentation](http://mcaroba.dyndns.org/misc/boc_caro.pdf) I put together last year: in slides 4 and 5 you can use the buttons to run the animation. The one in slide 4 includes plotting a gaussian with `pgfplots` changing the curve parameters between frames. You need to open it with the Adobe reader for it to play correctly.

Comment: thanks @Miguel. the same way I need to plot but in each frame I need separate curves to be presented. I have edited my Question above.

Comment: I have been working with `animate` myself lately. Check the example I posted on a question in TEX.SE: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/211190/enable-a-default-static-frame-for-incompatible-browsers-with-the-animate-package By clicking the buttons the graph will change. If you want gnuplot graphs to be displayed you'll need to use `\includegraphics{}` in each frame.